# Django initialize table with post_migrate not working

Tags: django

I want to initialize the database table with some predefined instances.

```
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

def initialize(sender, **kwargs):
    from .models import Address

    Address.objects.create(
        # address fields
    )
    print('Created')

class BackendConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'backend'

    def ready(self):
        print('Ready')
        post_migrate.connect(initialize, sender=self)
```

However nothing was created and nothing was printed after migration like the signal not triggered at all.

Comment: Data migrations are more appropriate for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations Especially since these work with *historic* models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's my first attemp that append the function in `Migration.operations`, told me the model has not been created yet.

Comment: but you should *not* append: you should make a specific data migration that runs *after* it has migrated the database to construct the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am dumbass.

Need to mention `default_app_config = 'backend.apps.BackendConfig'` in `__init__.py`